# Vim autoindent like emacs tab key

Tags: vim

I had many years of emacs experience but am new to vim.

In emacs, if my code is not properly indented, I can using tab key to indent my code no matter where my cursor is as long as it is on the current line.

Is there something equivalent in vim? I tried '>' key but it merely just inert more tabs for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`==` will re-indent the current line.

See

```
:help 30.3 
:help indent-expression
:help indent.txt
```

Comment: Great! That's what I have been looking for. Thanks